# CSS a.className:attr properties

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following html markup:

```
<span class="content_right_img">
 <a href="url" class="pic_link"><img src="lnk.gif" alt="alt" /></a>
</span>
<p>blah blah blah <a href="url">link text</a> more blah blah blah</p>
```

and the following CSS rules:

```
#mainContent a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
border-bottom: 2.5px solid #FF0;
}
#mainContent a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
border-bottom: 2.5px solid #FF0;
}
#mainContent a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
background-color: yellow;
}
.content_right_img {
float: right;
padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

The client wants the links to be 'highlighted' with the yellow underline, which works fine on text links.  We, however, do NOT want images enclosed inside of links to also have the border-bottom property.  Currently there is an underline in FF but not Safari (haven't looked at IE) and the area bellow the img receives the background color on hover.

I added class="pic_link" to the a tag in an attempt to write a separate set of href rules but had no success.

I tried:

```
.className
a.className
.className:link
a.className:link
```

but have not had any luck.  What is the proper way to assign css properties to different classes of a href?  Is there a better way entirely to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

```
a.className:link
a.className:visited
a.className:hover
a.className:active
```

should work

Comment: I had tried that before, and tried it again with no luck.  Is there any reason why FF would not be recognizing it properly?  I also tried "a.className:link img" with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

When you place an image inside a link. you should set `border="0"`

```
<span class="content_right_img">
   <a href="url" class="pic_link">
       <img src="lnk.gif" border="0" alt="alt" />
   </a>
</span>
```

Comment: I added that in but there was no change in FF.

Comment: Ok, If you have the "pic_link" class added all the links containing images then try this

    .pic_link{
         border:none !important;
         background:none !important;
     }

This worked well on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector:

```
#mainContent a.pic_link:link,
#mainContent a.pic_link:visited,
#mainContent a.pic_link:hover {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```